# JQueryMobile pagecontainer events and ModelViewController pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, model-view-controller

I'm in the process of cleaning up messy JavaScript code. In this code, I need to react to the `beforechange` event of the `pagecontainer` (for example to redirect the user to a login page).

In the messy code everything works as intended, i.e. the code got the event, reasoned about what to do, and did it.

However, I'd like to clean up the code by separating concerns using the MVC pattern.
For that, I have a view that knows when the `beforechange` event is fired for the corresponding page, and a controller that is informed by that view to react on that.

However, the controller must register itself in the view before the first event is fired. So far I had no luck achieving this, i.e. the view first informed all registered controllers, and only after that the controller registered itself.

What is a clean way to do something before `beforechange` is fired? Just writing the registration inside the outermost scope (is there a name for that?) does not help, as then the order of files is important. In other words, I need all JavaScript files to be parsed before I can actually start running code.

Is there another way to deal with such problems?

Comment: You can use mvc patterns for javascript like angular or backbone.js

Comment: And how is that related to my problem?

Comment: `pagecontainerbeforechange` works on all pages (views) except for first view?

Comment: Yes. But I think I solved it, posting an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It helped to load the JQueryMobile files after loading and initializing all of my own code. This way the views are ready and connected with the corresponding controllers, and the first `pagecontainer` event is fired only when I start loading the JQueryMobile files.